# Mutiple conditions in OS X bash script WHILE loop

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, osx-mavericks, sh

Basically what i want to do is read in a variable from std input and check if the variable is 1 or 2. if it is not i want to inform the user and ask again, i thought a while loop was made sense (i am using OS X Mavericks in a bash shell)

For a single condition this works:

```
read result

while [[ "$result" != "1" ]];
do
echo $result
echo "You must enter 1 or 2. Please try again: "
read result
done
echo "success"
```

but when i try to do an or condition:

```
while [[ "$result" != "1" ]] || [[ "$result" != "2" ]];
```

if i enter 1 or 2 into the terminal this doesn't match the input 1 or 2. I have also tried

```
while [[ "$result" != "1" ] || [ "$result" != "2" ]];
```

which produces a syntax error.

```
while [[ "$result" != "1" || "$result" != "2" ]];
```

and this doesn't match 1 or 2 either.
Does anyone know the correct syntax??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you need to use `&&` (AND) instead of `||`, so use:

```
while [[ "$result" != "1" && "$result" != "2" ]];
```

It is because you are checking if `$result` is `not 1 and not 2`

Comment: No worries, we all make these mistakes while writing code sometimes.

Comment: Yes but there is more than one way it can be written in BASH using different brackets.